# Associate Ext. Number with IP addr on H.323 voip call

Tags: voip, h.323

I simply need to associate an extension number to an ip-address on an H.225 message.

I have already recording RTP payloads, converting, mixing, everything but today, my extensions need to be ip-fixed .

All i need is the ext. number.

C/C++ code is welcome.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The association between IPs an E.164 numbers in H.323 is done through the gatekeeper. Take a look at the [GNU Gatekeeper](http://www.gnugk.org/).